# bootstrap.css doesn't show up in the browser

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, angular, gulp

I am setting up a project with angular 2 and gulp using this tutorial. http://blog.codeleak.pl/2016/03/quickstart-angular2-with-typescript-and.html

The only change I made is I added bootstrap to the package.json, but it doesn't show in the browser. It shows in the node_modules and the lib folder in my project in the IDE. But the bootstrap classes don't get applied if I use them. The bootstrap.min.css file doesn't show in the browser either.

I added the 2 lines about bootstrap to my gulp file

```
gulp.task("libs", () => {
    return gulp.src([
        'es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
        'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
        'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
        'reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
        'rxjs/**',
        'zone.js/dist/**',
        '@angular/**',
        'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
        'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
    ], {cwd: "node_modules/**"}) /* Glob required here. */
    .pipe(gulp.dest("build/lib"));
});
```

I added this line in index.html to include it

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Here is my project structure

[image: Project structure]

EDIT: Just to clarify, I see the bootstrap.css files copied over in the lib folder in the IDE, but I don't see it in the browser. See screenshot below from Chrome dev tools

[image: Screenshot from chrome dev tools]

Any clue as to what I may be missing? Github repo - https://github.com/richa008/Angular-starter-app-with-gulp

Comment: Are you sure if the bootstrap css is loaded in the browser? What if any errors do you see on browser console? How are you applying the css class?

Comment: It is not loaded in the browser, thats the problem. I don't get why it is not loading. I don't see any errors in the console either

Comment: try `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="../lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">` or `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Answer (score 0):

This should import all relevant files and directories:

```
    gulp.task("libs", () => {
        return gulp.src([
            'es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
            'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
            'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
            'reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
            'rxjs/**',
            'zone.js/dist/**',
            '@angular/**',
            'bootstrap/dist/**/*.+(js|css.map|css|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)'

        ], { cwd: "node_modules/**" }) /* Glob required here. */
            .pipe(gulp.dest("build/lib"));
    });
```

Comment: That does import all the bootstrap files in the folder, I can see them in the IDE. But they still won't load in the browser